# Powershell: Write-Progress of Export-Csv

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

This is a snipping of my code:

```
$alltheupdates | Export-Csv filename.csv
```

Is it possible to write the progress of an export?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many objects are in $alltheupdates:

```
0..($alltheupdates.count-1) | foreach {
    $percent = ($_/$alltheupdates.count)*100
    Write-Progress -Activity 'exporting to csv' -Status "$percent % Complete" -CurrentOperation "Exporting item # $($_+1)" -PercentComplete $percent
    $alltheupdates[$_]
} | Export-Csv filename.csv
```

Comment: This doesn't export the data I need, it does activate the progression bar though.

Comment: Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At M:\Technical Services\WSUS Reports\Check Updates Per Group\Get-LastUpdate.ps1:37 char:19
+     } | Export-Csv <<<<  WSUSUpdatePerClient.csv
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.
   Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: I made another adjustment (starting to count from 0).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out sometime last year that I can do this pretty easily on any command that takes ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName (like Export-CSV).  This will do the trick.  It will not include the %, because to calculate % you have to know the total number of items you'll be exporting.

```
Get-ChildItem |    
    Export-Csv -Path $home\files.csv -inputObject { $_; Write-Progress "Exporing to CSV" "$($_) " }
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: Thank you for this, if the total number of items is available would I then be able to use something like the answer Shay Levy gave me?